# Uploading images using bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, upload, bloc

I'm actually using the bloc architecture in my project and I'm actually stuck on the way I can upload some users pictures.

As it is a big project, I will minify the code I will show so, here is my database structure:

```
- users
  - my_user_1
    - name: "My user name"
    - dog_pictures:
      - dog_id_1:
        - health: "a int"
        - url: "my firestorage dog url"
    - cat_pictures:
      - cat_id_1:
        - power: "a string"
        - url: "my firestorage cat url"
```

My classes looks like that:

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  Dog dog;
  Cat cat;
  User(...);
}
class Dog extends ImageModel{
  String health;
}
class Cat extends ImageModel {
  String power;
}
class ImageModel {
  List<File> filesToBeUploaded;
  List<File> filesFromDatabase;
  List<File> filesToBeRemoved;
}
```

What I want to know is the best way to handle these files, is my ImageModel class correct ? As the user can add/remove images..
I firstly tried to handle this in the  `.toJson()` method, checking if there is files to be uploaded then get the url and put it in the json but I have the feeling that is a dirty way to achieve this.
So where should I handle the upload ? Also if you have any similar projects to share to me I will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

1. Either you can **store the Image on AWS and add the image path** in your class for API calls.
2. Otherwise, **Use multipart file upload** and send your files and data as a part-file to your API.
3. The last method is to **convert your image to base64** and add a base64 String to your class, but this method is *not so efficient*.

> If you have access to AWS use it to avoid wasting our server space or
> else upload it to our API with help of Multipart form data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already knew that, I just wanted to know where I could properly implement/call the upload ?

Comment: There are actions and events in bloc architecture.  Lets suppose you have a page to select the image you want to upload. On that page place a button to do the upload action. On button click, call the action to upload. Inside the action write the api call for upload. Then when the api returns data call an event to update the same on your UI